# Automapper map to IEnumerable from List<Expression<Func<T1, object>>>

Tags: c#, automapper

I currently map map properites from an anonymous type with the code

```
Mapper.CreateMap<T, CBoxItem>()
   .ForMember(m => m.Prop1, x => x.MapFrom(Prop1Source.Compile()));

 //followed by
 Mapper.Map(src, new List<CBoxItem>)

 //where  Prop1Source= Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

I want to do this for multiple properites from prop source - the following would also work

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<T, ListCboxItem>()
        .ForMember(m => m.Prop1, x => x.MapFrom(Prop1Source.Compile()));
        .ForMember(m => m.Prop2, x => x.MapFrom(Prop2Source.Compile()));
```

I'm running into problems when I want to map where `PropXSource = List<Expression<Func<T1, object>>>` and the destination property is an `IEnumerable`. I'm kind of stuck there.

I'd like to iterate over the expressions and add a map from the result of the expressions to the ienumerable property.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great answer, but its easier to just not use automapper for the more complicated ienumerable. Just copy it manually using nested for each loops.

So, to answer my question, automapper is not recommended for this situation as far as i know. I ended up using the nested loops to manually copy properties from T to ListCboxItem